# Where to get Java Native Access Platform sources?

Tags: java, jna, building

I am trying to build from sources that sources https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.5.0/ Java Native Access Platform version 5.5.0, and I am getting jna-platform-5.5.0.jar size - 1233K which is much less than https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.5.0/jna-platform-5.5.0.jar. In the same time, the recommended sources

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch 5.5.0  https://github.com/java-native-access/jna.git
```

Do not produce jna-platform-5.5.0.jar at all.
Could you tell me where to get real sources of Java Native Access Platform version 5.5.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both projects are in the same git repository, which you can browse [at the JNA GitHub site](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).

The `jna` artifact is built using the `build.xml` file in the project root.  The `jna-platform` artifact is built from `build.xml` in the [`contrib/platform`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/contrib/platform) subdirectory.

You can build both artifacts from the project root using:

```
ant dist
```

You may need the following packages if they aren't already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool libx11-dev libxt-dev texinfo
```

The latest released version is 5.9.0.  These later releases fix many bugs and add functionality and if you are building from source, would be a better choice than 5.5.0.

However, there is no 5.5.0 branch at the JNA site, so you're not able to check it out.  You may be getting the master branch (just released 5.9.0) anyway, and that would explain your differing jar sizes.

Comment: cd contrib/platform  ant produces the following log https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/de608c0133e3b6ecea177797f2a7c573

Comment: Is that just javadoc errors?  Try with `-Xdoclint:none`.  See https://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

Comment: I am sorry, could you explain me, how to pass this parameter? "ant -Xdoclint:none" doesn't work

Comment: Looking at the Linux test script [here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yaml) it may be that calling `ant dist` from the root directory builds both packages and includes other necessary settings.

Comment: Thank you! ant dist is the solution for me!